# Fill a list with user input via a for loop

Tags: python, c++, arrays, python-3.x, list

I know some basic C++ and I understand how to fill an array with user input via a for loop, but I would like to know how to accomplish that task in Python 3. I looked around here and there but could not really comprehend the way others were answering this question.

```c++
int size = 0;
cout << "Enter size: " << endl;
cin >> size;
array[size] = {0};
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cin >> array[i];
```

Hopefully someone can explain this to me in a simple way. As you can tell, I just started C++ about 5 to 6 months ago and Python3 around the middle of this month.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `C++` you need to define the array size first, in `python` lists you don't do that, they will grow accordingly while you add elements to them. For example to code that in `python` I would write the equivalent code like this (I added `print` statement to demonstrate `a_list` growing):

```py
size = int(input("Enter size: "))  # for input 3
a_list = []
for i in range(size):
    a_list.append(input())  # for input 1, 2, 3

print('python list:', a_list)

>>> python list: ['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: I ran this python code and it demonstrates this example very nicely! It is honestly crazy in how little lines I could get input into a list and sort that list, while in C++ you'd have like 4 loops just doing these tasks! I am also going to see what range does, I never seen that before!

Comment: @Bowen check this out: `a_list = [ input() for i in range(int(input("Enter size: ")))]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, lol thanks man your hilarious  the one liner. Python is honestly crazy, I just started it, I have been learning C++ in my classes for the past 5 months and the amount of things you can do with Python in so little code is impressive.

Answer (score 0):

There is first of all one thing I want to say about the C++ part you wrote.

This part is not officially supported by C++:

```
cin >> size;
array[size] = {0};
```

Variable length arrays (VLA's) are valid in C99 and might work with some C++ compilers as a C extension, but it is not an official part of the language. In C++ they should not be used, because it might result in not portable code. Please use something like a `std::vector` instead.

Please keep in mind that the syntax used above in the highlighted code part is not valid. First of all a type is missing, and any form of default initialization is not valid for a VLA.

On topic:

```
size = int(input('Size:'))
my_array = []

for i in range(size):
    val = int(input())
    my_array.append(val)
```

Comment: so are you saying that I should not use "using namespace std?"

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add the name where I was talking about. I was talking about VLA's (variable length arrays) which are part of the C language (version 99, called C99). These are NOT part of the C++ language, but are sometimes supported by some compilers as a C extension. You might want to read something more about it right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Comment: `array[size] = {0}` is almost certainly invalid in C, including C99.   It is an assignment, not a definition of a VLA.  In C++, its meaning depends on how `array` was previously defined (e.g. what its elements are) but the result is almost certainly either a diagnosable error or undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter You're right about the initialization an the missing type, but working with VLA's is valid in C99. I tried to make that clear, but when reading my comment again I noticed I didn't even mention 'VLA'. In a comment above I already tried to explain the Topic Starter the point of my comment.